# git pull --rebase --preserve-merges

Tags: git, git-rebase

Short version:
Do you need to preserve-merges only if you explicitly merged after you did a local commit? What exactly happens otherwise? Does it reapply your committed code to the merged branch?

Please explain when it is useful to `git pull --rebase --preserve-merges` vs. a regular `git pull --rebase`?
I read about an issue with `git pull --rebase` here:
http://notes.envato.com/developers/rebasing-merge-commits-in-git/
That could cause code changes to be duplicated.

I read here: [When will `git pull --rebase` get me in to trouble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590260/when-will-git-pull-rebase-get-me-in-to-trouble)

That it only happens if you basically rebase after some the commits have been pushed.

So I am not sure I understand when I would need `git pull --rebase --preserve-merges` and if it's ever bad to use vs.  `git pull --rebase`.

Comment: I think I understand it now thanks to that link. As I see it, if I don't preserve merges it just adds the code I wrote in all the commits after the most recent current commit disregarding any branches I created and merged? If I preserve merges, it moves the commits forward but maintains the diverging branches.

Comment: I edited the question. If I understand correctly, if you commit (locally) and then fetch and merge and then pull and rebase it will duplicate your changes somehow?

Comment: I use `git pull --rebase=merges`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Technically—and I claim this is a bit stupid of git, the `pull` script (it's a shell script) should just do this for you—you have to run `git pull --rebase=preserve` rather than attempting to use `git pull --rebase --preserve-merges`.  (Or, as I noted in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364636/git-pull-rebase-preserve-merges/21365623#comment32216030_21364866) on [Vlad Nikitin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21364866/1256452), you can set `branch.name.rebase` to `preserve` to get the same effect automatically.)

In other words, you should *never* run `git pull --rebase --preserve-merges` as it (incorrectly) passes `--preserve-merges` to the `fetch` step, instead of to the `merge`-or-`rebase` step.  However, you *can* run `git pull --rebase=preserve`.

The question of when (and whether) to use any kind of rebase, whether merge-preserving or not, is more a matter of opinion.  Which means it really does not go well on stackoverflow in the first place. :-)

Still, I'll make one claim here: you should only rebase if you know (in a sort of general sense) what you are doing,<sup>1</sup> and if you *do* know what you are doing, you would probably prefer a merge-preserving rebase as a general rule, although by the time you've decided that rebasing is a good idea, you will probably find that a history that has its own embedded branch-and-merge-points is not necessarily the correct "final rewritten history".

That is, if it's appropriate to do a rebase at all, it's at least fairly likely that the history to be rebased is itself linear, so that the preserve-vs-flatten question is moot anyway.

---

#### Edit: add drawing

Here's a drawing of part of a commit graph, showing two named branches, `mainline` and `experiment`.  The common base for `mainline` and `experiment` is commit node `A`, and `mainline` has a commit `G` that is not on the `experiment` branch:

```
...--o--A-------------G   <-- mainline
         \
          \ .-C-.
           B     E--F     <-- experiment
            \_D_/
```

Note that the `experiment` branch has a branch-and-merge within it too, though: the base for these two branches is `B`, one branch holds commit `C`, and the other branch holds commit `D`.  These two (unnamed) branches shrink back to a single thread of development at merge commit `E`, and then commit `F` sits atop the merge commit and is the tip of branch `experiment`.

Here's what happens if you are on `experiment` and run `git rebase mainline`:

```
$ git rebase mainline
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: B
Applying: C
Applying: D
Applying: F
```

Here's what is now in the commit graph:

```
...--o--A--G               <-- mainline
            \
             B'-C'-D'-F'   <-- experiment
```

The "structural branch" that used to be there on branch `experiment` is gone.  The `rebase` operation copied all the *changes* I'd made in commits `B`, `C`, `D`, and `F`; these became the new commits `B'`, `C'`, `D'`, and `F'`.  (Commit `E` was a pure merge with no changes and did not require copying.  I have not tested what happens if I rebase a merge with embedded changes, either to resolve conflicts or, as some call it, an "evil merge".)

On the other hand, if I do this:

```
$ git rebase --preserve-merges mainline
[git grinds away doing the rebase; this takes a bit longer
than the "flattening" rebase, and there is a progress indicator]
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/experiment.
```

I get this graph instead:

```
...--o--A--G               <-- mainline
            \
             \ .-C'.
              B'    E'-F'  <-- experiment
               \_D'/
```

This has preserved the merge, and hence the "internal branchiness", of `experiment`.  Is that good?  Bad?  Indifferent?  Read the (very long) footnote!

---

<sup>1</sup>It's a good idea to learn "what rebase does" anyway, which in git (alas!) pretty much requires learning "how it does it" as well, at least on a medium-level.  Basically, rebase makes *copies* of (the changes from your earlier) commits, which you then apply to (your or someone else's) later commits, making it "seem like" you did the work in some other order.  A simple example: two developers, let's say Alice and Bob, are both working on the same branch.  Let's say that Marketing has asked for a feature code-named Strawberry, and both Alice and Bob are doing some work to implement `strawberry`, both on a branch named `strawberry`.

Alice and Bob both run `git fetch` to bring `strawberry` over from `origin`.

Alice discovers that file `abc` needs some change to prepare for the new feature.  She writes that and commits, but does not push yet.

Bob writes a *description* of the new feature, that changes file `README`, but has no other effect.  Bob commits his change and pushes.

Alice then updates file `feat` to provide the actual feature.  She writes and commits (separately) that, and is now ready to push.  But, oh no, Bob beat her to it:

```
$ git push origin strawberry
...
! [rejected]        strawberry -> strawberry (non-fast-forward)
```

Alice should then fetch the changes and *look at them* (not just blindly merge or rebase):

```
$ git fetch
...
$ git log origin/strawberry
```

(or using `gitk` or whatever—I tend to use [`git lola`](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html) myself, and `git show` individual commits if/as needed).

She can see from this that Bob only changed the `README`, so her changes are definitely not affected either way.  At this point, she can tell that it's safe to rebase her changes onto `origin/strawberry`:

```
$ git rebase origin/strawberry
```

(note that there are no merges to preserve), which makes it *look* (in terms of git history) like she first waited for Bob to update the documentation, and only then actually started to implement the changes—which are still split into two separate commits so that it's easy to tell, later, whether the change to file `abc` broke anything else.  Those two separate commits are now adjacent, though, so it's easy to tell, later, that the *point* of the change to `abc` was to enable the change to file `feat`.  And since the change to `README` comes first, it's even more clear that the this was the point of the change to `abc`.  Not that it would be hard to tell even if Alice just did:

```
$ git merge origin/strawberry
```

instead, although that creates a merge commit whose only point seems to be to say "Alice started in on `abc` before Bob finished updating `README`, and finished `feat` after", which is not really helpful.

In more complex cases, where Bob did more than just update the documentation, Alice might find that it's best to rearrange her own commits (probably more than two in this case) into a new, different linear history, so that some of Bob's changes (this time, probably more than one commit) are "in the middle", for instance, as if they had co-operated in real time (and who knows, maybe they did).  Or she might find that it's better to keep her changes as a separate development line that merges, perhaps even more than once, with Bob's changes.

It's all a matter of what will provide the most useful information to someone(s)—possibly Alice and Bob, possibly other developers—in the future, if and when it becomes necessary to go back and look at the (apparent, if rebased, or actual if not) sequence of events.  Sometimes each individual commit is useful information.  Sometimes it's more useful to rearrange and combine commits, or drop some commits entirely: for instance, changes that proved to be a bad idea.  (But consider leaving them in just for the value of pointing out "this was a bad idea so don't try it again in the future" as well!)

Comment: Detailed and informative as alw... wait, I wrote that already today, didn't I? +1 anyway. For knowing if a rebase is "possible": http://stackoverflow.com/a/21362208/6309

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand when the preserve is needed/helpful? Is it just a matter of opinion? This the part I'm not confident I fully understand "That is, if it's appropriate to do a rebase at all, it's at least fairly likely that the history to be rebased is itself linear, so that the preserve-vs-flatten question is moot anyway.". What exactly does preserve not flatten? Merges that were done previously on purpose between branches?

Comment: The `preserve` setting preserves merges.  It's not possible, in general, to describe those as "between branches" without defining precisely what *you* mean by "branches", as git leaves the term itself ambiguous.  I can *draw* what it does, if that helps...

Comment: I guess the root of the issue is that the company I work for and I myself dislike meaningless merge commits. Since I am somewhat of a cautious git user and mostly stash to handle multiple changes that aren't committed yet I suppose I'd never run into a situation where the rebase will have unwanted results (and instead will only accomplish the goal of avoiding unneeded empty merge commits). I think that I know how to avoid the pitfalls with rebase now.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite: if you avoid creating empty merges, you usually won't have any merges on a chain you're going to rebase, so preserve/no-preserve is flipping a switch that affects nothing.  If you *do* accidentally create an unwanted, empty merge, you can rebase it away.

Comment: @zehelvion, one of the useful cases for this is if you work on a product with many developers and multiple supported versions out in the wild. In my company, a fix to an earlier version needs to be merged up the versions to the current one (each version has it's own release branch so that we can track this). If you are doing such a merge, and someone happens to commit ahead of you, rebase --preserve-merges can be quite useful to avoid having to re-merge. Of course, you could always turn on rerere and just re-do the merge - horses for courses.

Comment: @torek , can u pls have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58913987/default-value-of-rebase-flag-in-git-pull-rebase

Answer (score -2):

`git pull --rebase` is the same as `git fetch` and then `git rebase`, so `git pull --rebase --preserve-merges` is the same as  `git fetch` and then `git rebase  --preserve-merges` . You can get good answer about `git rebase  --preserve-merges` here [What exactly does git's "rebase --preserve-merges" do (and why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915430/what-exactly-does-gits-rebase-preserve-merges-do-and-why)

Comment: AFAICT, `git pull` won't take the `--preserve-merges` option anyhow. The article linked in the question states that you need to `fetch` and then `rebase`

Comment: @Hasturkun: there's a newish `--rebase=preserve` option (or you can set `branch.<name>.rebase` to `preserve`).